# How To Get Log Cat for INSTALL_FAIL_DEXOPT?

Tags: android, eclipse, apk, dexopt

I am receiving a "App did not install" message when I try to install, on a physical device, an APK that is being generated from Eclipse. (I know Eclipse is old, this what I have to use right now)

I am able to run directly from Eclipse to my device, and to the emulator.

I ran adb against my phone and got this response:

```
adb install 16063008.apk 
4519 KB/s (9638251 bytes in 2.082s)
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/16063008.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT]
```

I ran adb against my emulator and got this response

```
adb install 16063009.apk 
654 KB/s (8943664 bytes in 13.335s)
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT: Extracting package failed for com.awesome.app]
```

I keep seeing tips that suggest looking at the Log Cat output, but where do I look at Log Cat? In Eclipse when I generate the APK? Or is there somewhere to look while I am installing the APK to the device?

Pretty desperate here, any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Have the same issue using Android Studio. Tried to wipe the emulator and tried to clean and rebuild the project. No luck.